# Direct linking to tabulous tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, tabulous

I'm trying to link direct to tabs made using the [tabulous plugin](http://git.aaronlumsden.com/tabulous.js/). My tabs are set up so:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB 1</li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB 2</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs_container">
<div id="tabs-1">content here</div>
<div id="tabs-2">content here</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and on another webpage I want to link to one of these tabs. I've tried:

```
<a href="NameOfPageWithTabsOnIt.html#tabs-2">Link</a>
```

but this just loads up the page with the first tab active. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a "active" class to the tabs.
If you navigate around you remove the current "active" class and append/create the class on the new tab.

```
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    $('#tabs ul li a.active_tab').removeClass('active_tab');
    $(this).closest('#tabs ul li a').addClass('active_tab');
});

$('#tabs ul li ul li.tabsub a').click(function() {
    $('#tabs ul li a.active_tab').removeClass('active_tab');
    $(this).parents('#tabs ul li a').addClass('active_tab');
});
```

Maybe something like this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that would involve significant changes to the plugin's code, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I think you can write this as standalone code, but if you would like to keep it at plugin actions then yes, you would have to dig further. But this option should work without you having to touch the plugin.